# Spinner onitemselected listner issue

Tags: android

Im try to create a spinner dynamically on press of a button.

this is what i did:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.leave_balance);

spinner = new Spinner(this);
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list);
    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

Button  b = (Button)findviewbyid(R.id.button1);
b.setonclicklistener(new Onclicklistener){
   public void onClick(View v) {
            spinner.performClick();


        }
 spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            Toast.maketext(context,"selectedspinner",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
}
}
```

My issue is im not able to get that toast, ie the spinners onitemselectedlistner is not triggering.

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.. Thanks

Comment: why you have written `spinner.performClick();`?

Comment: That would perform click on spinner

Comment: you have try new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() instead of OnItemSelectedListener?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spinner need to add in a parent to get call on `onItemSelected`

1. Add the sppiner in XML and set width and height 0dp (may set visibility Invisible not gone).
2. Get that using `findViewById`.

Comment: this works but why does it not happen when i try to add a spinner dynamically. any reason you would like to share

Comment: Ok if i get the parent layout by its id and if i add the spinner dynamically to that layout would it work

Answer (score 2):

spinner.performClick() call the onclicklistener and not onItemclicklistener.

Use spinner.performitemclick(.....);

Comment: Yes, but you can get event of OnItemClickListener when click to spinner list item.

Answer (score 0):

Have try at this.

```
onCreate()
{

spinnerLocation = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerSettingLocation);

ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.location_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerLocation.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinnerLocation.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnLocationSpinnerItemSelectedListener());

}



public class MyOnLocationSpinnerItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
        View view, int pos, long id) {
        Toast.maketext(context,"selectedspinner" + pos,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }




    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
      // Do nothing.
    }
}
```